# Angularjs 1.2 Explorer 8 doesn't respond

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to make work a form in internet explorer 8 and angularjs 1.2. I may say that it works perfectly in last versions of Chrome and Firefox.

The site to see this: http://barcimaster.com/solicitud_de_presupuesto/1

I made a fiddle also to see a simple version: http://jsfiddle.net/r01010010/e9kvd/11/ but it doesn't work!

So, what i'm missing. I already tried using:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

But nothing happens... i tried to debug the function but never gets into the function "update".

Comment: Do you have any console.log statements? window.console is not defined in IE8

Comment: no Brocco,  i'm not using it.